# Find n most referenced records by foreign_key in related table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have a table `skills` and a table `programs_skills` which references `skill_id` as a foreign key, I want to retrieve the 10 most present skills in table `programs_skills` (I need to count the number of occurrence of `skill_id` in `programs_skills` and then order it by descending order).
I wrote this in my `skill` model:

```
  def self.most_used(limit)
    Skill.find(
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
        'SELECT programs_skills.skill_id, count(*) FROM programs_skills GROUP BY skill_id ORDER BY count DESC'
      ).to_a.first(limit).map { |record| record['skill_id'] }
    )
  end
```

This is working but I would like to find a way to perform this query in a more elegant, performant, "activerecord like" way.

Could you help me rewrite this query ?

Comment: Please define "more  elegant". Your query seems to be the simplest, straight forward, clear and understandable one that satisfies your requirement. What more do you want? As for performance your query has no filtering (where) so it *must* scan either every row on the table or every entry on the skill_id index , if one is available. But either way it is not going to get any better. This seems to be about as good as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your query by:

```
WITH
T AS
(
SELECT skill_id, COUNT(*) AS NB, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS RNK 
FROM   programs_skills  
GROUP  BY skill_id
)
SELECT wojewodztwo, NB
FROM   T
WHERE  RNK <= 10
```

This use CTE and windowed function.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
ProgramsSkills.select("skill_id, COUNT(*) AS nb_skills")
.group(:skill_id).order("nb_skills DESC").limit(limit)
.first(limit).pluck(:skill_id)
```